# Show differences for two (almost identical) video files

Tags: video, compare

I have a folder containing several video files and I have a backup of that folder. rsync tells me that the checksum of a couple of the video files differ from the ones in the backup.

Is there a way to find out what the difference is?

Something like the frame numbers of the frames that differ would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you think there are only minor differences, start with the command line tool ‘cmp’. That will show what bytes are different. If you get a lot of output, the files are very different.